# convert hexadecimal to bytes in python

Tags: python

I  want  to display the  number

```
0x40000000
```

as

```
01000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

with the  leading 0 and formatting above

Comment: You mean you want to convert hexadecimal to binary.

Comment: with byte  formatting  I  think

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the most flexible way, but:

```
>>> num = 0x40000000
>>> bits = bin(num)[2:].zfill(32)
# '01000000000000000000000000000000'
>>> ' '.join(bits[i:i+8] for i in xrange(0, 32, 8))
'01000000 00000000 00000000 00000000'
```

Umm, couldn't post earlier as my broadband was down, but slightly more flexible version...

```
def fmt_bin(num):
    bits = bin(num)[2:]
    blocks, rem = divmod(len(bits), 8)
    if rem:
        blocks +=1
    filled = bits.zfill(blocks * 8)
    return ' '.join(''.join(el) for el in zip(*[iter(filled)]*8))
```

Comment: You could use `bits = format(num, '032b')`. You could get the padding with `pad = -8 * (-num.bit_length() // 8)`, which uses floor division to round up to a multiple of 8.

Comment: @eryksun I updated the answer slightly using something I had open and was playing with, but broadband went down - it appears to work, still not 100% sure if I'm happy, but oh well...

Comment: I prefer `xrange` over the copied/zipped iterator in this case. Based on the calculated `pad` value, I had something like this in mind: `bits = '{0:0{1}b}'.format(num, pad)`.

Answer (score 1):

This will handle arbitrarily large positive numbers:

```
def long2str(n):
    if n == 0:
        return '00000000'
    s = []
    while n > 0:
        s.append('{:08b}'.format(n & 255))
        n = n >> 8
    return ' '.join(s[::-1])

num = 0x40000000
bignum = 0x4000000040000000
print long2str(num)
print long2str(bignum)
```

Output:

```
01000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
01000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 01000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```